# USB install server or desktop

Tags: system-installation, usb, live-usb, usb-drive

Is it feasible to create a bootable USB that would give the option to install Server or Desktop? i.e. one usb with both server and desktop on it and the option to select either at install.

Comment: Yes, definitely. Try googling "multi usb live" to see a few of your options.